# Why is the server side rendered content replaced by vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering

I have a simple index.html file with the following mounting point for vue:

```
<div id="server-rendered-test" server-rendered="true">server</div>
```

As you can see I pretend that the server has rendered the template. In my main.js I have the following code to mount vue:

```
const serverRenderedTest = new Vue({
  el: '#server-rendered-test',
  data: {
    text: 'client'
  },
  template: '<div id="server-rendered-test">{{ text }}</div>'
});
```

I expected vue to "hydrate" the existing DOM, but it doesn't since the end result (after vue kicking in) is:

```
<div id="server-rendered-test">client</div>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what the issue is that you are experiencing and the question?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the data object within the Vue component?

Comment: I am also facing this problem. I expect the client side mechanism use the generated html as is, and only modify it at further application lifetime. In the following Nuxt.js demo (https://hello-world.nuxtjs.org/), the behavior seems correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydration means that Vue will try to use existing server-rendered elements instead of creating new ones (see explanation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-server-renderer#client-side-hydration)). So in your case, it will find the already rendered `div#server-rendered-test` and replace the text in it with fresh data.

You're not missing anything, this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Is there a way to tell vue (client side) that the server has rendered `#server-rendered-test` with `text: 'server'`, to avoid the data being replaced by fresh data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The point of server side rendering support in client side frameworks is to get some static HTML to show to the user before your JS initializes. For that to work, you are supposed to use the same data on both sides. Try providing some more information on your intentions so we can help you better.

Comment: I wanted to archieve exactly what you described. So for now I set a global var `window.initialComponentXState = { text: 'server'}` and pass that into the data property of the (client side) component. Thanks for you answer! This was the piece I was missing.

Comment: Yup, that's the way to go, official Vue examples use the same principle of passing the initial state through a [global variable](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/f5ca53ac72356b2ae963a90cb61da0dc85d8d2b2/server.js#L89-L91).